# Drupal 8 Views or Pixture Reloaded paging/formatting problem

Tags: views, theming, 8

Looks like I may have tripped over yet another bug in either [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) or [Pixture Reloaded](https://www.drupal.org/project/pixture_reloaded) in D8.

I created a view to show a simple content type I created called Newsletters. I can use the pager supplied by views to navigate to page 2 without a problem, but when I click page 3 or Next Page I get a screwed up display.

Excerpts from page 2 that displays properly.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Excerpts from page 3

[image]
[image]
[image]

View that I created. 
[image]
Do you think this is a Views problem or a Pixture Reloaded problem?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

Looks like I had a corrupted instance of my Newsletter content type. When I deleted it the problem went away.